# Is this a good or bad practice to declare the functionality of a pipe as static method and use it out of templates?

Tags: angular

It's been asked in StackOverflow commonly how to use the functionality of a pipe outside of templates.

From Angular V6 on, the function `formatDate` beneath the built-in `date` pipe is exported.

I've written a pipe with the functionality declared as a static method of the pipe class. The static method is called by the `transform` method of the pipe, as well as called (prefixed with the pipe class name) in components or services.

Pipe definition:

```js
@Pipe({name: 'isLongTermBackupClass', pure: true})
export class IsLongTermBackupClassPipe implements PipeTransform {
  static isLongTermBackupClass(storageClass: string) {
    return ['GLACIER', 'DEEP_ARCHIVE'].includes(storageClass);
  }

  }

  transform(storageClass: string) {
    return IsLongTermBackupClassPipe.isLongTermBackupClass(storageClass);
  }
}
```

Usage in other .ts files:

```js
import {IsLongTermBackupClassPipe} from '@shared/pipes/is-long-term-backup-class-pipe';

// ...
  result = IsLongTermBackupClassPipe.isLongTermBackupClass(value);
// ...
```

I think it has slightly better encapsulation than separating the function in another place.

But while it was being reviewed, my review peer said that it's not a good practice since the pipe is only used in templates and the component should not know about the pipe.

My question is: is this a good or bad practice.

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you move the logic to a service which will be used by your pipe and others?

Comment: @RafiHenig because it's just a very simple transformation.

Comment: @RafiHening The sample in the question is updated. Thanks for your comment.